# How to remove all fragments from a ViewPager using a FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I have a `ViewPager` that I use as a photo gallery using a `FragmentPagerAdapter`.
The `ViewPager` has no really special code.
The `FragmentPagerAdapter::getIem(int position)` returns a new Fragment with an `ImageView` with the photo corresponding to the position. It has a list of Images that is set before.
I have a side menu that allows to view another gallery, however I can't get the photos to update to the new set of photos. I change the list of Images in the `FragmentPagerAdapter` and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` however the Fragments never get re-created and hence they don't update.

I tried several of the solutions found on SO but with no success (Fragments do not update):

- returning `POSITION_NONE` from `FragmentPagerAdapter::getItemPosition(Object object)`
- trying to update the `ImageView` inside the `Fragment`: I don't really know where I could do that.
- setting `ViewPager::setOffscreenPageLimit(0)`
- setting `ViewPager::setAdapter(null)`

What I want is that it goes back through `FragmentPagerAdapter::getIem(int position)` but I can't seem to achieve this because it leaves the fragments in the `FragmentManager`.
Is the only way out to make my own `PagerAdapter`?

Comment: Any solution found for this?

Comment: The design of our app changed since then and so the activity is destroyed and recreated, which flushes the FragmentManager.

Comment: Oh, its too bad really this shouldnt be so complicated, very unfortunate